# Mailhog not receiving mail with Warden/Magento2 setup

Tags: macos, magento2, apple-m1, warden, mailhog

I followed the steps at https://docs.warden.dev/environments/magento2.html to setup a `magento2` environment and followed the instructions exactly.  However, I'm not seeing any emails come through to MailHog when I do things like create a customer account from the Magento frontend or submit a customer Forgot Password request.

I've tried on 2 separate computers (both Macbook Pro 2021 M1's) and got the same results.  How do I fix this?  Alternatively, does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never determined why this issue was happening, but I did find a solution.  I uninstalled Warden which I had previously installed via `brew` per the Warden docs.  I then installed the multi-arch fork instead which is available at https://github.com/drpayyne/warden-multi-arch and magically all my issues disappeared including other problems I was experiencing like ElasticSearch only working sporadically and some Magento modules pulling the wrong file paths.

Since then everything seems to be working flawlessly on both machines.

I should also note that things run significantly faster as well.